# Retrieve and display master details tabular data with checkbox using AngularJS and get checkbox selected row details

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

1. I need to  display data in tablur with checkbox using angularjs.
2. when i check checkbox get all details of that perticular row .

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is a JS framework and you can find what you need with a quick search, if data is from a db try http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp, in this example it's a mysql db hooked up via the PHP script then parsed to JSON. There's just lots of ways of achieving this but you need to start and show us what you have tried then we answer more specifically.

Other questions we may need answers to: Do you know HTML? Do you know JS? Do you know CSS? Do you know SQL language?

Steps you make take:

1. Build a HTML page in your root folder and name it: index.php
2. Add this to the body:

{{ x.Name }} {{ x.Country }}

var app = angular.module('myApp', []); app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) { $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php") .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;}); });

3. Create a file in root dir called: customers_mysql.php
4. Copy all the code from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php and put it your customers_mysql.php
5. Fire up MySql or PHPmyAdmin and create a db and tables to match what is noted in customers_mysql.php. Or create this via Cpanel first and set your username and passwords for the db and tables
6. Add your username and passwords in customers_mysql.php
7. Open your page from and if your server is setup correctly go to your website and navigate to the index.php page e.g. mywebsite.com/index.php
8. If you're lucky then it should all work
9. Once the above is working then add another question/comment regarding your checkbox and we can advise how to add a checkbox that upon checked will pull a row from the db.

I hope this helps.

---

Quote of the day: *Take the first two steps on your own, should you fall on your third this where we will help you.*